# why R does not recognise columns and rows as they are supposed to be?

Tags: r

The code given bellow is to extract  values of one region and write that to a text file(there are 365 binary files in the directory).
The problem which I am facing is that all my files are binary with size of 360 rows and 720 columns.
I specified that in this line:

```
file2 <- matrix(data=file,ncol=720,nrow=360)
```

but I got an error:

> Error in mean(file2[X, Y], na.rm = TRUE) : subscript out of bounds.

and then I rewrote the above line as:

```
file2 <- matrix(data=file,ncol=360,nrow=720)
```

I put ncol=360 and nrows =720 which is not right. But that worked and I didn't get any error. However, the results were not correct.

```
X <- c(364:369) ;   Y <- c(82:92) #####   for sellected region
extract <- vector()
dir1 <- list.files("C:\\Users\\Climate_Rad_f_GAMMA_%d.img", full.names = TRUE)
listfile<-dir1()
for (i in c(1:365))
{
    conne <-  file(listfile[i], "rb")
    file <-  readBin(conne, double(), size=4,  n=720*360, signed=T)
    file2 <-  matrix(data=file,ncol=720,nrow=360)  
extract[i] <- mean(file2[X,Y],na.rm=TRUE)
    close(conne)
    write.table(extract,"C:\\Users\\sam.txt")
}
```

Comment: can't you format the code better?

Comment: I attempted to salvage this question, but I had to make an educated guess or two regarding some of your code. Please review it to make sure it reflects your question.

Comment: Readers of this question should know that it was cross-posted today on r-help and has apparently been answered: The key being that the binary files needed to be read properly and that the x indices 364:369 were causing R's row,col order for "[" access to throw the error.

Comment: It would be good if the OP were willing to post the answer from r-help as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
mean(file2[X,Y],na.rm=TRUE)
```

You are selecting rows X and columns Y.  You have but 360 rows.  You might want this instead:

```
mean(file2[Y,X],na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks.I have done so.I think my problem is that the data are generated by C++ as float32.I am defining them here as double. R just have  integer, double , real.Can anyone know which of these represent float32.